# CROSS JOIN in SQL Server to find a distance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got two tables called `hotels` and `hotel locations`. In the `hotels` table I have `HotelId, hotelName`. In the `hotelLocations` table I have `HotelId, HotelNorthing, HotelEasting`. `HotelId` is a foreign key that references `HotelId` in the `hotels` table, `HotelNorthing` and `HotelEasting` are UTM co-ordinates that hold the northing and easting values for the hotels.

I would like to find, using this data the 2 hotels that are closest to each other and display with a query the hotel name and id from the hotels table and the distance from the calculation. I previously tried all sorts of cross joins but came up short. I used the Pythagoras theorem to calculate the distance between the hotels but the structure of an appropriate query has eluded me.

Comment: SHOUTING your questions is really not needed. It won't get you answers any faster, and it actually makes it harder to read. Also, please don't add tag info in the subject; the tag system works very well here, and doesn't need the assist. :-)

Comment: You might want to check out gis.stackexchange.com, it might be more suited for a question like this.

Comment: version is sql server 2008. This is not a GIS question, i believe its just an advanced sql query that might be needed to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming MS SQL 2008 or later I'd use the built in geography type:

```
insert into locations (name, location) values
('Hotel1', 'Point(138.58 -34.92)'),
('Hotel2', 'POINT(138.97 -34.78)'),
('Hotel3', 'POINT(138.00 -34.00)'),
('Hotel4', 'POINT(138.57 -34.01)'),
('Hotel5', 'POINT(138.50 -34.03)'),
('Hotel6', 'POINT(138.49 -34.04)'),
('Hotel7', 'POINT(138.88 -34.04)')


declare @StartLocation geography
select @StartLocation = location
from Locations 
where name = 'Hotel1'

select location.STDistance(@StartLocation)
from locations
```

This will give you the distance from Hotel1 to all the other hotel's, then it's just a matter of sorting the list and taking the top 2.

---

EDIT: To calculate from every hotel to every other hotel:

```
create table locations
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name varchar(50),
    Location geography
)

insert into locations (name, location) values
('Hotel1', 'Point(138.58 -34.92)'),
('Hotel2', 'POINT(138.59 -34.93)'),
('Hotel3', 'POINT(138.00 -34.00)'),
('Hotel4', 'POINT(138.57 -34.01)'),
('Hotel5', 'POINT(138.50 -34.03)'),
('Hotel6', 'POINT(138.49 -34.04)'),
('Hotel7', 'POINT(138.88 -34.04)')

select l1.name, l2.name, l1.location.STDistance(l2.Location)
FROM Locations l1
JOIN Locations l2 on l2.ID < l1.ID
```

---

EDIT 2:
Split Hotel Names out into seperate table:

```
create table locationNames
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Name VARCHAR(50)
)
insert into locationNames (Name) VALUES
('Hotel1'),
('Hotel2'),
('Hotel3'),
('Hotel4'),
('Hotel5'),
('Hotel6'),
('Hotel7')

create table locations
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    Location geography
)

insert into locations (location) values
('Point(138.58 -34.92)'),
('POINT(138.59 -34.93)'),
('POINT(138.00 -34.00)'),
('POINT(138.57 -34.01)'),
('POINT(138.50 -34.03)'),
('POINT(138.49 -34.04)'),
('POINT(138.88 -34.04)')

select ln1.Name, ln2.Name, l1.location.STDistance(l2.Location)
FROM Locations l1
JOIN Locations l2 on l2.ID < l1.ID
JOIN LocationNames ln1 on ln1.ID = l1.ID
JOIN LocationNames ln2 on ln2.ID = l2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but it's not exactly what i'm after. I would like the distance to be calculated for every hotel, not just from hotel1 to the others. Sort of like a cross join i believe

Comment: @IQ_HiGh I've updated my answer. It now shows the distance between every hotel

Comment: Thanks Greg. In my situation though, the names of the hotels are in one table, while the locations are in the other. Your solution is quite nice but then i'd have to do an additional join to bring in the locations which would mean having a self join and an inner join inside the same query

Comment: How would you approach this if you had hotel names and id in one table, and then the hotel location in another?

Comment: It's a pretty simple join - just join both tables back onto the hotel names table. See my 2nd edit for an example

Comment: Thanks, i must say that i've seen so many unnecessarily complex joins that the thought of it sometimes puts me off. Good to know that there are guys like you out there. Thanks a bunch....will be testing this once i get to the office tomorrow

Comment: no worries. These ones are pretty basic joins. l2.ID < l1.ID joins all hotels less than the current id (hotel2 to hotel1, hotel 3 to hotel2 and hotel1, so on). You can reverse that to get l2.ID>l1.ID (resulting in: hotel1 to hotel2,3,4,5,6,7 hotel2 to 3,4,5,67) or even l2.ID <> l1.ID giving each hotel to every hotel but itself (hotel1 to hotel2 and 3 and 4 and 5, hotel2 to hotel1 and 3 and 4 and 5, hotel3 to hotel1 and 2 and 4 and 5, and so on)